# Getting the mean value for every Id in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Imagine I have a data frame with 2 columns

```
Id    Value
12    13
32    3
6022  11
9142  231
12    23
119   312
...
```

and I want to get the mean value for each "Id". Do you know of any fast way of doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to average columns based on ID in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487367/how-to-average-columns-based-on-id-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond aggregate, other options include by and ddply (in plyr).

Comment: I think you know that this would be considered as a low quality answer. I'd appreciate if you would edit and include some codes. Cheers.

Answer (score 8):

One possible solution using `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(Value ~ Id, data=tmp, FUN=mean)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness basic solution is `tapply`:

```
tapply(data$Value, data$Id, mean)
```

(or using `with` as `with(data, tapply(Value, Id, mean))`)

Answer (score 2):

I heart reshape:

```
cast(x, Id ~ ., mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also `by` will do the job, yet the output will be tricky.