# tapply with non numeric values

Tags: r, dataframe, character, tapply

I'm in a class learning R right now, and I'm stuck on a problem.

We set up the following data frame:

```
Column1=c(rep("control",300),rep("ConditionB",300),rep("ConditionC",300))
Column2=(900,mean=100,sd=10)
data=data.frame(Column1,Column2)
```

It runs fine, but then he asked us the following request:

"Use tapply to find the means of "control", "ConditionB", and "ConditionC"".

I have tried ten different ways of putting it, and I just come out with errors. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I guess you missed a `rnorm` in your second line. Just try `tapply(data$Column2,data$Column1,mean)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the mean value for every Id in a data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797083/getting-the-mean-value-for-every-id-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you missed an `rnorm()`. You can also use the vector `c("control","ConditionB","ConditionC")` and `times = 300` instead of repeating `rep()` 3 times.

```
Column1=rep(c("control","ConditionB","ConditionC"), times = 300)
Column2=rnorm(900,mean=100,sd=10)
data=data.frame(Column1,Column2)
tapply(data$Column2,data$Column1,mean)
```

Comment: @MaryHeske No need to thank me. Just mark the answer as "Accepted" if it fixes your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to use `tapply`, try hadley's package dplyr:

`data %>% group_by(Column1) %>% summarise(mean(Column2))`