# aggregate multiple variables based on id for different timestamp in R

Tags: r, timestamp, mean

I'm having problem with calculating the average for 2 variables in my data. I have temperature and speed collected as shown below. I want to minimize the data and have `hourly` readings only (without minute). I want to take the average of the `temperature` and the `speed` for each id based on the `time` and the `day`.

```
ID    temp  Speed   Day    Hour    Minute    Latitude    Longitude
1      3      20    1      11      10      38.9294865  -77.2479055
1      5      25    1      11      30      38.9294865  -77.2479055
1      5      30    1      12      12      38.9294865  -77.2479055
1      6      20    1      12      40      38.9294865  -77.2479055
2      1      40    2      11      05      38.9294771  -77.2478712
2      5      30    2      11      50      38.9294771  -77.2478712
2      2      20    2      12      30      38.9294771  -77.2478712
2      8      10    2      12      40      38.9294771  -77.2478712
```

My desired data looks like this:

```
ID    temp  Speed   Day    Hour    Minute    Latitude    Longitude
1      4      22.5   1      11      00      38.9294865  -77.2479055
1      5.5    25     1      12      00      38.9294865  -77.2479055
2      3      30     2      11      00      38.9294771  -77.2478712
2      5      15     2      12      00      38.9294771  -77.2478712
```

I thought about creating a column with the hour and the minute like this :

```
Data$HM <- as.date(with(Data, paste(Hour, Minute ,sep=":")), "%H:%M")
```

And then based on the new column I was thinking to try this code:

```
AvrgData<- aggregate(Data[, 2:3], list(Data$HM), mean)
```

However my code is not correct.
Any suggestions will be much appreciated!
I went through these links but still not helping with the results I want.

[How to average columns based on ID in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487367/how-to-average-columns-based-on-id-in-r)

[Merge three different columns into a date in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26334763/merge-three-different-columns-into-a-date-in-r)

Thank you

Comment: For starters, `as.date` is not a function - try `as.Date`. After you've done that, check the results of `Data$HM` - Dates in R do not store hours and minutes. Try `as.POSIXct` instead to get a date/time. Or don't worry about the date conversion at all, just use the `paste`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `aggregate` you can get `mean` of `temp` and `Speed` grouped by `ID`, `Day`, `Hour`, `Latitude` and `Longitude` and create a column for `Minute` with value as 0.

```
transform(aggregate(cbind(temp, Speed)~ID + Day + Hour + Latitude + Longitude, 
          df, mean), Minute = 0)

#  ID Day Hour Latitude Longitude temp Speed Minute
#1  1   1   11    38.93    -77.25  4.0  22.5      0
#2  1   1   12    38.93    -77.25  5.5  25.0      0
#3  2   2   11    38.93    -77.25  3.0  35.0      0
#4  2   2   12    38.93    -77.25  5.0  15.0      0
```

The same logic implemented in `dplyr`, would be

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID, Day, Hour, Latitude, Longitude) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(temp, Speed), mean) %>%
  mutate(Minute = 0)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), temp = c(3L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 8L), Speed = c(20L, 25L, 30L, 20L, 40L, 
30L, 20L, 10L), Day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Hour = c(11L, 
11L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L), Minute = c(10L, 30L, 12L, 
40L, 5L, 50L, 30L, 40L), Latitude = c(38.9294865, 38.9294865, 
38.9294865, 38.9294865, 38.9294771, 38.9294771, 38.9294771, 38.9294771
), Longitude = c(-77.2479055, -77.2479055, -77.2479055, -77.2479055, 
-77.2478712, -77.2478712, -77.2478712, -77.2478712)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```